# DateFormat and Base64

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I trying to encode the date using following code.

```
String[] anArray = {"Value1","Value2" DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance.format(new     Date())};
StringBuilder strBulder = new StringBuilder("tracker=");
strBuilder.append(new String(Base64.encode(anArray[0].getBytes())))
          .append("&param1=")
          .append(new String(Base64.encode(anArray[1].getBytes())))
          .append("&timestamp=")
          .append(new String(Base64.encode(anArray[2].getBytes()))).toString();
```

The problem I am facing that encoded timestamp always remains same.

Comment: Can you print the anArray[2]

Comment: following is my test result: note these is only 2 character difference between two result
May 18, 2014 3:39:11 PM
tracker=VmFsdWUx&param1=VmFsdWUy&timestamp=TWF5IDE4LCAyMDE0IDM6Mzk6MTEgUE0=
May 18, 2014 3:39:25 PM
tracker=VmFsdWUx&param1=VmFsdWUy&timestamp=TWF5IDE4LCAyMDE0IDM6Mzk6MjUgUE0=

Comment: Here is the output: anArray[2] = "5/18/14 2:27 AM" AND anArray[2].getBytes() = [53, 47, 49, 56, 47, 49, 52, 32, 50, 58, 50, 55, 32, 65, 77]     ...in my case I am getting the same timestamp

Comment: Can you print "DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance.format(new Date())"? Probably it is not containing the seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
String.valueOf(new Date().getTime()) ;     //encode this String
```

is generally preffered way as third value in the array instead of using formatted date

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance.format(new Date()));
```

And formate this long formatted date to String using

```
String strDate = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance.format(new Date(Long.valueOf(anArray [2])));
```

Where ever you are using it for display.

Comment: Thanks, I shall give it a try.